# Como se impletementa class PasswordChangeView Django

Tags: python, django

La pregunta es la que se encuentra en el titulo. Hago esta pregunta ya que en internet no encuentro nada en concreto de como implementar esta class.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**url.py**

importamos

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

Y hacemos esto

```
path('config/password_change/', 
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), 
    name='password_change')
```

Ahora django buscará un template llamado (**password_change_form.html**)
el valor predetermindado es `registration/password_change_form.html`

puedes cambiar el nombre de este archivo de esta manera.

```
    path(
        'change-password/',
        auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='change-password.html'),
    ),
```

Luego en el **registration/password_change_form.html**

```
<form class="" action="{% url 'password_change' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn ">Update Password</button>
</form>
```

Hasta este punto has hecho el 50% del trabajo, ahora django te va a redirigir a una vista llamada PasswordChangeDoneView que es **La página que se muestra después de que un usuario ha cambiado su contraseña.**

---

url.py

```
path('config/password-change/done/', 
    auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), 
    name='password_change_done')
```

**registration/password_change_done.html**
Pones el mensaje que quieras

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Password changed!</h4>
  <h6>Your password is successfully changed. Now use your new password while logging in. Thank you.</h6>
</div>
```

Para mas información: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView